# (Python) How to replace a certain substring in a specific line in a .txt file while keeping the other content without overwriting it

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to change the substring "Available: Yes" to "Availability: Rented Out" from a specific line that the user choose but my code overwrites the entire txt file to the modified string that I've chosen. My goal is just to modify substring of the chosen line and keep everything else on the .txt file.

Here is my code:

```
f = open("Car_Database.txt", "r")
row_number = f.readlines()
print("Here is the list of cars in the Database!")
for line in row_number:
    print(line, end="")

index = int(input("\nPlease enter the row that you want to return! \nEnter 0 for the first 
column and 1 for the second and so on.\n:"))

row_number = row_number[index].replace("Availability: Yes", "Availability: Rented Out")

with open("Car_Database.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(row_number)
    print("Your modification has been updated!")
    for line in row_number:
        print(line, end="")
```

[image: Content of Car_Database.txt]

[image: Content of Car_Database.txt after running]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning the changed string to the variable that was previously the list, just assign it to the element.

So in code:

Instead of

```
row_number = row_number[index].replace("Availability: Yes", "Availability: Rented Out")
```

use

```
row_number[index] = row_number[index].replace("Availability: Yes", "Availability: Rented Out")
```